# Unable to create table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a table in Oracle using the below syntax using %type

```
Create table emp_avg
(
emp_id HR.employees.emp_id%type,
dept_id HR.employees.dep_id%type
):
```

When I tried executing it is throwing an error.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2):

The given code is not valid. Try the below code.

```
Create table emp_avg as
Select e.employee_id, e.department_id from HR.employees e where 1=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid syntax.  The point of an anchored type declaration (the `%type` syntax) in PL/SQL is that when the underlying data type changes, the PL/SQL code uses the new type automatically.  But that doesn't work when you're defining a table where Oracle has to know the actual data type when it writes a data block to disk and can't just dynamically recompile the table when the parent data type changes.  When you create a table, you have to specify actual data types.